# Packages in Fedora 11

Tags: fedora, rpm

I'm trying to find a list of the packages that Fedora 11 installs.
I guess this is either on the .iso for the install DVD or part of the anaconda package.
In particular I'd like a minimal list.

I understand that this might not be the right question; it's possible that at install
time a minimal Fedora does not install any packages, but just copies files from the DVD. Can anybody confirm this?

Thanks,

Bob.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `comps.xml` file in your first ISO, particularly:

```
<group>
  <id>base</id>
  <packagelist>
    <!-- find your data here -->
  </packagelist>
</group>
```